# STM32F103 keeps on rebooting

Tags: embedded, stm32, reset, stm32f1

I am using STM32F103. I observed one of my boards keeps on rebooting. I flashed the same code into another board and everything works fine on another board.
I erased and flashed the faulty board as well but doesn't help. Is it possible by chance to recover this board.
I am sure that this issue is specific to that board. All the components look good (visually inspected).

Comment: If you can get it to happen with a debugger attached, or have a way of getting data out of it, the `Control/Status register` in the RCC has bits to tell you what the reason for reset was.

Comment: Is watchdog enabled? It can be if the board is from China and uC is "second hand". It it is a Chinese copy of the uC - it is quite common problem.

Comment: If the software works on one board and not the other, it is not likely to be a problem with the code and therefore not an SO problem.  Is it possible that you have enabled the watchdog on start-up in the option bytes and are not maintaining the watchdog?  Reset the option bytes erasing the flash is not enough.

Comment: yes this is chinese board. and regarding option bytes, I was erasing the board before flashing. is it like it will keep option byte even after reset.